# What’s does “if the dog bites once mean?”

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Someone has recently messaged me the phrase “if a dog bites once”, I do not understand what this phrase could mean and my friends do not understands it either. I’m getting a threatening feeling off it haha, thanks for answers!!

Answer (score 9):

> **If a dog bites once, it will likely bite again** with the second attack often more vicious that the first.  [sciencedaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/11/101109133233.htm)

Typically a metaphor: if someone can do something bad once he or she can do it again.  Be forewarned.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably an extended reference to the saying...

***"Once bitten, twice shy"***

> "...said when you are frightened to do something again because you had an unpleasant experience doing it the first time."

[-Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/once-bitten-twice-shy)

In other words:
 **Be aware.**

Your original quote shows few hits.